# Flask-mysql returning integer value instead of string

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have troubles with flask-mysql(https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) when i try to get users from database using cursor.execute function, cursor returns number instead string of users
My code goes like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,url_for,request,session,logging,redirect,flash
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # do some setup
    return app

app = create_app()

app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_USER"] = "username"
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] = "password."
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_DB"] = "databasename"


mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route("/database")
def database():
    cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
    dbs = cursor.execute("select user from mysql.user")
    
    
    return str(dbs)


def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")
```

When i try access 127.0.0.1:5000/database i get this in browser:

```
9
```

That number 9 actually corresponds with number of users in database.

Comment: [cursor.execute()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) returns an iterator, not single column value from a row.

Comment: yeah, try print(dbs) and see what it looks like :)

Comment: what you are expecting from this? list of users?